# Joomla magazine article for JSE

Tags: discussion, joomla

A couple of weeks ago, I submitted an issue to the Joomla CMS on Github asking the PLT if adding a menu item for JSE to the **Help** dropdown in the Joomla backend would be allowed. Some were ok with this, however having talked to @George Wilson last night, he made a good point that it may not be good idea as it could possibly attract the most stupid of questions which will most likely get closed. Therefore it's would not be a good idea if Joomla officially recommend JSE as a help resource.

We agreed that writing an article for the Joomla magazine would be a great idea to get the attention of more developers.

So I'll make this a community wiki and maybe we could all contribute edits to mock up an article to submit advertising JSE and explaining the benefits of it.

Comment: Hmmm... Do we have a more nuanced goal than just "get more people"? Are we trying to attract more people to answer questions? Are we looking for people to ask questions? Not that you can't write an article to cover both, but I think we definitely want to explain why you should come here to do either of those activities.

Comment: @DavidFritsch - For me personally, the 2 main goals are attracting more people and gaining knowledge. Attracting more means more questions asked which allows more people to answer questions. I for one gain a fair amount of knowledge by participating in JSE. I've learned how to do things in Joomla that I didn't realise were available and also improve the way I think about coding. I can only assume this applies for others out there and both of the above go hand in hand

Comment: I have this pinned to my browser but haven't had a chance to contribute yet. I will though!

Comment: Same, been quite busy but will probably start today during my free afternoon at work

Answer (score 1):

## Title:

**Joomla! Stack Exchange**

## Body:

**What is JSE?**

Joomla Stack Exchange (JSE) is an interactive resource of problems and solutions for Joomla users. The steadily growing JSE community is part of Stack Exchange, a network of 139 communities, all run and managed by experts and enthusiasts of different topics. What makes these communities different from regular forums is that there's no chit-chat and distractions. Questions are asked and answered. Period.

Like most communities, JSE is growing, but with almost 2000 unique questions so far (duplicated questions are flagged as such by the community), most of them with several great answers and alternative solutions, it's nothing short of an excellent resource for any Joomla related problem.

And if no solution is available to a specific problem, a new question can be asked by anyone, registered or not, for free.

---

**Why use it?**

As time goes on, more and more users are moving away from the official Joomla forum which contains so much old, deprecated code, and moving over to Stack Overflow, and now Joomla Stack Exchange.

The unique way the Stack Exchange sites are constructed, with no discussion and where each post is a stand-alone answer to the original question, makes the order of the posts irrelevant. The most popular answers will rise to the top of the list, right below the question.

This way, finding the best answer can easily be achieved by looking at the votes each answer has. The highest voted and/or accepted answer will normally provide a solution to your question. Other popular alternatives will be highly visible too.

---

**Who owns/moderates the JSE community**

The beauty of all the Stack Exchange communities, including JSE, is that every user is part of the process of making a better Joomla resource. By asking and answering questions, reputation is earned by the means of a points system. The more points a user has, the more tools are available to influence how the community evolves. Low quality posts can be flagged as such by most users, edited and improved if possible by others, or deleted by moderators.

**How does it differ to other resources that are already available?**

> I think this could be answered in the first section. Correct me if I'm wrong

---

*------------------------Towards the bottom of the article-------------------------------*

JSE (Joomla Stack Exchange) is more than just a resource it is a tool and like all good tools to get effective results you need to use it properly.

- Checklist of things to include in your question.
- Things to do before posting your question.

Unlike the forum, JSE is not for discussions(*NOTE) It is a place to find information quickly.

*NOTE Make mention of CHAT n META site in relation to discussions

Comment: I'm also short on time, but these were a few points that I wanted to see in the article. Use as much or as little as you like. I'll try to add to it later.

Comment: "This is a call to arms for Joomla Jedis (experts) to share their Joomla mojo (knowledge)."

Comment: love this sentence ^^ :) Thanks for starting off, appreciated

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Excellent edit @johanpw :)